# Error while getting data from NavigationContext

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I am creating a Reminder app using C# in Visual Studio 2013. One of the pages is for launching the notification.

My code is :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

       string Combobox = "";
       string Content = "";

     NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("param1", out Combobox);

     NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("param2", out Content);

     param1TextBlock.Text = Combobox;
     param2TextBlock.Text = Content;     

    }
```

But the errors occur in this part :

```
     NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("param1", out Combobox);

     NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("param2", out Content);
```

The Error is :

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationContext.QueryString.get'

Any idea?

Comment: Just a guess but your variable names "Content" and maybe "Combobox" might interfere with built in types. Try to rename these two variables.

Comment: Is it an universal app, or a Silverlight app?

Comment: The compiler seems to be trying to access the type `NavigationContext` instead of the property defined in your page (by inheritance from `PhoneApplicationPage`), but I have trouble understanding why. You should try using the `this` keyword and see if you get a more explicit error message: `this.NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("param1", out Combobox);`

Comment: I tried this way ,and i have this error :                                                Error 1 'FastHealing.ShowParams' does not contain a definition for 'NavigationContext' and no extension method 'NavigationContext' accepting a first argument of type 'FastHealing.ShowParams' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Don't initialize the strings to `""`. As you are passing them as `out` parameter, only declare them.

Comment: So there's definitely something wrong with your class... Can you copy/paste the class definition?

Comment: I tested this code on device & its working fine. No exception, nothing!
I suggest you to give different variable names, clean the solution & rebuild. Try testing on device.

Comment: Thanks ... I solved this .. just replaced NavigationContext  with Frame.Navigate .

Comment: Then it means you're using WinRT, not Silverlight ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> MyStringsList = new List<string>();

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName),MyStringsList);
```

this code is used for navigation with parameters, you can get these parameters at the navigated to page in OnNavigatedTo event :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{

   List<string> MyRecievedParameters = e.Parameter as List<string>;
}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work in silverlight wp8.1 apps

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have created "Windows Phone" application project, while you need to create "Windows Phone Silverlight" to be able to access the NavigationContext class.